# Create two string columns from one string column that was subtracted

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table named *lex* with a string column named `CHARGE_CODE_DESCR`.

The rows consist of strings with this structure:

```
USPOB000 - SMS usluga- Pobjeda
U211 - Video i Data pozivi
...
...
```

I want to take the first word (Before the `-`) into a column named VALUE and all the rest of the words (After the `-`) into a second column named TEXT.

For example, from the first two rows i want to get these results:

```
VALUE     TEXT
USPOB000  SMS usluga- Pobjeda
U211      Video i Data pozivi
```

To get the first word I wrote this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT regexp_substr(CHARGE_CODE_DESCR,'\w+') as VALUE from lex
```

To get the rest of the text I wrote this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(Text, 3, LENGTH(Text)) as TEXT
FROM
(
   select SUBSTR(CHARGE_CODE_DESCR, INSTR(CHARGE_CODE_DESCR, '- ')) as Text from lex
)
```

How can I combine them both in one query so it will create  the desired two columns from every row of data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I combine them both in one query

As simple as this. There is really no need to involve regular expression functions:

```
/* sample of data */
with t1( col) as(
  select 'USPOB000 - SMS usluga- Pobjeda' from dual union all
  select 'U211 - Video i Data pozivi'     from dual
)
/* actual query */
select substr(col, 1, instr(col, '-')-1) as val
     , substr(col, instr(col, '-') + 1)  as text
 from t1
```

Result:

```
VAL                            TEXT
------------------------------ ------------------------------
USPOB000                        SMS usluga- Pobjeda
U211                            Video i Data pozivi
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below solution:

```
WITH
  data AS
  (SELECT 'USPOB000 - SMS usluga- Pobjeda' AS str FROM dual
  UNION SELECT 'U211 - Video i Data pozivi' AS str FROM dual)
SELECT
    regexp_substr(str, '(.*?) -', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Value,
    regexp_substr(str, '- (.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Text
  FROM data
;
```

The idea is to use the reference to the matched group (last parameter of `regexp_substr`) - 1 means: 'give me whatever is in the first group, where each group is identified by being enclosed in a set or parentheses'. I also used non-greedy * operator (followed by a question mark `?` so the * operator doesn't swallow the hyphen `-`.

Read more in [Oracle documentation about regexp_substr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm)

Edit: using your table and column name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    regexp_substr(charge_code_descr, '(.*?) -', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Value,
    regexp_substr(charge_code_descr, '- (.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Text
  FROM lex
;
```

Comment: This is working for the two specific rows of data, but how can I combine my queries with this ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is - just put your table `lex` in the `FROM` clause, and delete the `WITH` clause from my example.